# preg_quote issue in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, preg-quote

I'm testing preg_quote() function in search function in Laravel. I found out a strange behavior - "+" is not escapes, but remove from the output.

```
preg_quote("a + b"); // "a b"
```

Tried to call same function without laravel staff from cli

```
php test.phpa // a \+ b
```

Seems Laravel makes some affect on function/output/something else...

> Laravel 5.7. /
>   php 7.3.1

Comment: Can you show us your search function, how you output it, and to where? A `+` sign in a URL is a space in the resulting `$_GET` parameter and would need to be encoded as `%2B`.

Comment: I'm using postman to test. 
request: `http://localhost:8000/api/users?skip=0&search=a + b`
function first line:  `dd(preg_quote($request->search));`

The main problem is that "+" is the only one special character which is not escaped. I've tested with a string with all special chars from function doc.

Comment: @ceejayoz for this request `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - ` I've got this output 
` \. \\   \* \? \[ \^ \] \$ \( \) \{ \} \= \! \< \> \| \: \- ` - everything is escaped, "+" ignored / removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using postman to test. request: `http://localhost:8000/api/users?skip=0&search=a + b` function first line: `dd(preg_quote($request->search));`

As I suspected, this isn't a problem with PHP or Laravel, but that your URL parameters should be [`urlencode`](https://php.net/urlencode)d. (This'll happen if you're `GET`ing via a `<form>` element, or by building a URL using Laravel's built-in URL builder, but if you're making a manual Postman request it's up to you.)

A `+` in a URL's query string corresponds to a space on the server. It must be escaped as `%2B`, as must characters like `#`. You can do this via `urlencode`.

`http://localhost:8000/api/users?skip=0&search=a%20%2B%20b`